# Array in array - search form, get category and tags

Tags: php, arrays, search

Good day, everyone!

Simple PHP questions for guru in PHP arrays.

I have a script, which get data from сsv-like file (with pipe "|" delimeter).

Data in *keymin.txt* (i don't want to use a DB, just csv', it; like CMS you know, but i need more lightweight):

*~ title|image|some text|category|tags with comma delimeter ~*

```
title|image_url|apple text|apples|products, fruits, dishes
title|image_url|apple text|apples|products, fruits, dishes
title|image_url|apple text|apples|products, fruits, dishes
title|image_url|orange text|oranges|products, fruits, dishes
title|image_url|pearl text|pearls|products, fruits, dishes
```

And get all data with file() to array:

```
$key = file("keymin.txt");
```

1. Help me to create search form with search in **title and text columns** and get results from main array - return those strings.
2. Can you help me to return only strings with the same category? (I will create a link with GET parameter)
3. Can you help me to create tags pages (I will create links for them)?

So I need to lookup to array(s) in array. Thank you.

Ok. 1. First almost done

*~50 shades of shittycode~*

```
$find = "it";
$key = file("keymin.txt");

foreach ($key as $line){
    $eachLine = explode("|", $line);
        $titleColumn = $eachLine[1];

        $titleColumn;
        $titleArr = explode(" ", $titleColumn);
        if (in_array($find ,$titleArr)  ){ $found = true;}

    if(isset($found)){echo $line."\r\n";}
 }
```

It doesn't search only full word, it get all matches.

Comment: Can you post what you have so far and where your code fails? That would be nice

Comment: That's not how this site works. SO is _not_ a free coding service where you give us assignments and we just do it for you.. It's up to _you_ to write your code and if you run into some _specific_ issue with your _existing_ code, we're here to help. Then you need to show us what you've tried, expected result and the results your getting. This question is currently off-topic for being too broad and doesn't contain any attempts what so ever.

Comment: Hint: use `array_combine` to set keys. `array_column` and `in_array` for search and `array_filter` for find categories

Comment: Magnus Eriksson, i understand, sorry if it hurt your feelings. i'm just to newbie now and did not work with all arrays functions.

Comment: dWinder, thank you! Very useful. I'll try

Answer (score 0):

To get data

```
foreach($key as $k)
{
  list($title, $image_url, $apple_text, $apples, $pfd_temp) = explode('|', $k);
  list($product, $fruits, $d) = explode(',', $pfd_temp);
  echo $title;
  echo "$fruits $fruits";
}
```